# position() being treated as a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am working on a slider, here is the code for it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // MAKE SLIDER WIDTH EQUAL TO ALL SLIDES WIDTH
    var totalWidth = 0;
    $('.slide').each(function() {
        totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    var maxScrollPosition = totalWidth - $(".slider_wrap").outerWidth();

    function slideMove($targetSlide) {
        if ($targetSlide.length) {
            var newPosition = $targetSlide.position().left;
            if (newPosition <= maxScrollPosition ) {
                $targetSlide.addClass('slide--active');
                $targetSlide.siblings().removeClass("slide--active");
                $(".slider").animate({
                    left : - newPosition
                });
            }
            else {
                $(".slider").animate({
                    left : - maxScrollPosition
                });
            };
        };
    };
    $(".slide").width(totalWidth);

    $(".slide:first").addClass("slide--active");
    $(".next_post").click(function(){
        var $targetItem = $(".slide--active").prev();
        slideMove('.slide');
    });
    $(".prev_post").click(function(){
        var $targetItem = $(".slide--active").next();
        slideMove('.slide');
    });
    });
```

While I would expect this to work, I am getting an error that says: TypeError: $targetSlide.position is undefined. From the if statement in the function slideMove. Why doesn't this work? I am still learning jQuery so sorry if it is an obvious answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
slideMove('.slide');
```

to this

```
slideMove($('.slide'));
```

In your method `slideMove` you are expecting a JQUERY DOM ELEMENT where as you are giving it just a STRING which is class name of that particular DOM element

Answer (score 0):

YO! you change it to this

```
...

$('.next_post').click(function(){
  var $targetItem = $('.slide--active').prev();
  slideMove($('.slide'));
});

$('.prev_post').click(function(){
  var $targetItem = $('.slide--active').next();
  slideMove($('.slide'));
});

...
```